# Date format changes

Tags: r

I am just preparing the some table like `cols<- c("Metrics",as.Date(Sys.Date()-8,origin="1899-12-30"),as.Date(Sys.Date()-1,origin="1899-12-30"))` , and I am not getting the expected output. Any one please help.
Output : "Metrics" "17927"   "17934"

```
cols<- c("Metrics",as.Date(Sys.Date()-8,origin="1899-12-30"),as.Date(Sys.Date()-1,origin="1899-12-30"))

cols<- c("Metrics",as.Date(Sys.Date()-8,origin="1899-12- 
30"),as.Date(Sys.Date()-1,origin="1899-12-30"))
```

Expected Output:

```
"Metrics" "2019-01-31"   "2019-02-07"
```

Comment: Place it in a `list` as vector can hold only a single type i.e. `list("Metrics", as.Date(Sys.Date()-8,origin="1899-12- 
30"),as.Date(Sys.Date()-1,origin="1899-12-30"))`

Answer (score 1):

**1) character output** If you are looking for a character vector as the result then convert the `Date` class components to `character`.  Also note that the `as.Date` shown in the question is not needed since `Sys.Date()` and offsets from it are already of `Date` class.  Further note that if `Sys.Date()` were called twice right at midnight it is possible that the two calls might occur on different days.  To avoid this possibility we create a `today` variable so that it only has to be called once.

```
today <- Sys.Date()
cols <- c("Metrics", as.character(today-8), as.character(today-1))
cols
## [1] "Metrics"    "2019-01-31" "2019-02-07"
```

**1a)** This could be made even shorter like this.

```
cols <- c("Metrics", as.character(Sys.Date() - c(8, 1)))
cols
## [1] "Metrics"    "2019-01-31" "2019-02-07"
```

**2) list output** Alternately if what you want is a list with one `character` component and two `Date` components then:

```
today <- Sys.Date()
L <- list("Metrics", today - 8, today - 1)
L
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Metrics"

[[2]]
[1] "2019-01-31"

[[3]]
[1] "2019-02-07"
```

If we already had `L` and wanted a character vector then we could further convert it like this:

```
sapply(L, as.character)
## [1] "Metrics"    "2019-01-31" "2019-02-07"
```